# android send data in listview to server

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-fragments, android-listview

I retrieved some data from server and populated these data into a listview. I want to use part of the data i received and send it back to server. How do I do it? When I click on one of the list item it will start another activity with buttons, when i click one of the button the app will use part of the data in that listitem(which was previously retrieved from server)  and send it back to server. I'm new to android programming, i'm stuck and have no idea how do I do this. Could someone advised me? I know how to send data to server by manually typing the data i want to send.

This is how i get the data from server and populated into a listview and i want to send a particular phonenumber received back to server when i click that listview item:

```
public class TabActivityQueue extends Fragment {

ListView list;
TextView number;
TextView info;
TextView remark;
TextView statuss;
Button Btngetdata;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "http://172.22.85.235:8080/Qproject/servlet/Qaction?action_flag=find";

//JSON Node Names 
private static final String Table2 = "table2";
private static final String phonenumber = "phonenumber";
private static final String peoplenumber = "peoplenumber";
private static final String remarks = "remarks";
private static final String status = "status";

JSONArray table2 = null;



 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            //This layout contains your list view 
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_activity_queue, container, false);


             return view;
        }


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
Btngetdata = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.getdata);
Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        new JSONParse().execute();  
    }
});

}

private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
     public ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   number = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.number);
     info = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.info);
     remark = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.remark);
     statuss = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.statuss);
   pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
   pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
   pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
   pDialog.setCancelable(true);
   pDialog.show();



}

@Override
   public JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    return json;
}
 @Override
public void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
     pDialog.dismiss();
     try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            table2 = json.getJSONArray(Table2);
            for(int i = 0; i < table2.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = table2.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String number = c.getString(phonenumber);
            String info = c.getString(peoplenumber);
            String remark = c.getString(remarks);
            String statuss = c.getString(status);




            // Adding value HashMap key => value


            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(phonenumber, number);
            map.put(peoplenumber, info);
            map.put(remarks, remark);
            map.put(status, statuss);

            oslist.add(map);
            list=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list);





            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist,
                    R.layout.list_view,
                    new String[] { phonenumber,peoplenumber, remarks,status }, new int[] {
                            R.id.number,R.id.info, R.id.remark,R.id.statuss});

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     Intent ThreeButton = new Intent(getActivity(), ThreeButton.class);
                     startActivity(ThreeButton);
                 } 
                }
            );

            }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                 Intent ThreeButton = new Intent(getActivity(), ThreeButton.class);
                 ThreeButton.putExtra("phone", oslist.get(position).get("phonenumber"));

                 //u can put all variables similarly...
                startActivity(ThreeButton);
             } 
            }
        );

 In  ThreeButton Activity

 onCreate(){

       Intent data=getIntent();
       data.getString("phone");
       Log.v("phone",phone);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have access to data in listview in your next activity. Instead of trying get that from there, you can pass needed data to new activity. Before call startActivity put into intent data using methods putExtra. By the way, if you are working with JSON you should check Gson library to parse json